# Autocomplete jQuery UI em segundo plano no modal do Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, modal, autocompletar, fullcalendar

Estou fazendo um autocomplete com jQuery UI e está funcionado como deveria, porém a lista do autocomplete fica "em baixo" do modal,

na imagem abaixo da para ver....

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando foi digitado a letra "A" no form "paciente" o auto complete funcionou, exibindo os registros do banco com pacientes que tem a letra "A" no nome, porém a lista do autocomplete fica "em baixo" do modal....

Na imagem dá para ver que o último nome da lista do autocomplete é o "Goulart"

Preciso de ajuda para que a lista seja apresentada em 1º plano, ou seja "em cima" do modal.

Answer (score 3):

Coloque um `z-index: 1050` na classe `.ui-autocomplete`, que é a classe da `ul` da lista do autocomplete. Basta inserir no CSS:

```
.ui-autocomplete{
   z-index: 1050;
}
```

Dependendo da ordem do carregamentos das libs CSS, será preciso incluir um `!important`:

```
.ui-autocomplete{
   z-index: 1050 !important;
}
```

**Veja:**

```js
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
```

```css
.ui-autocomplete{
   z-index: 1050 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Abrir modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

         <div class="ui-widget">
           <label for="tags">Digite "a": </label>
           <input id="tags">
         </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou 100%! Muito obrigado!